# Find a continuous bijective function with the given form and its inverse

Tags: inverse-function, plane-geometry, plane-curves, bezier-curve, smooth-functions

I am looking to find a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and its inverse $g^{-1}$, such that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous, smooth, and bijective, such that:

$$
g(x,0)=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix}
$$

So the problem is to find an expression for a function $g(x, y)$ and its inverse $g^{-1}(x, y)$, which satisfies the criteria above in general when $y\ne0$. I realise there are probably infinitely many solutions to this problem, so any specific solution would be appreciated.

To give some background to the problem, I'm trying to find a general method for finding a function which can transform one quadratic [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to another one using an invertible transformation of 2D space. I intuitively feel that it should be possible to solve this problem, and I think this problem can be reduced to finding an invertible transformation from one specific Bezier curve to another, in which both  Bezier curves start at $(0,0)$ and end at $(1,0)$, the "input" Bezier curve to the function $g$ has a central control point at $(0.5,0)$, and the output Bezier curve has a control point at $(a,b)$. I believe this more general problem can be solved using the answer to this question and simple affine transformations which are easily found.

(Sorry if this problem is overly open-ended or under-constrained. I initially tried a solution of the form $g(x,0)=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x+y \end{pmatrix}$, but this in general is not bijective: see the image and code shown below for lines of $g(x,y)$ in the case $a=1,b=1$ with $x\in[-1,2],y\in[-1,1]$ with $y$ constant along each line. A specific function that satisfies the criteria stated in the problem would be great, but the problem is I'm not entirely sure how to go about finding a valid solution to this problem, so even a suggestion of how to get started would be useful. I'm also not 100% sure that there is a solution to this problem, so if this is the case then a proof that there is no solution would obviously be valuable instead).

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 2)
for y in np.arange(-1, 1.1, 0.2):
    plt.plot(2 * (1-x) * x + x*x, 2 * (1-x) * x + y, "g--")
```

### Background

A linear Bezier curve interpolates between two points $P_0$ and $P_1$, parameterised by a continuous variable $t \in [0, 1]$:

$$
B(t) = (1 - t) P_0 + t P_1
$$

A quadratic Bezier curve defined by three points $P_0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ interpolates between two linear Bezier curves, one from $P_0$ to $P_1$, and one from $P_1$ to $P_2$:

$$
\begin{align}
B(t) &= (1 - t) \Bigl( (1 - t) P_0 + t P_1 \Bigr) + t \Bigl( (1 - t) P_1 + t P_2 \Bigr) \\
&= (1 - t)^2 P_0 + 2t(1 - t)P_1 + t^2 P_2
\end{align}
$$

If we set $P_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T, P_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}^T, P_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T $, we get the following parametric curve:

$$
\begin{align}
B(t) &= (1 - t)^2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 2t(1 - t) \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} + t^2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 2a(1-t)t+t^2 \\ 2b(1-t)t \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

We can view this curve as a transformation of 2D space, denoted by $g(x, y)$, along a line of constant $y = 0$:

$$
\begin{align}
g(x,0) &= B(x) \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The question now is how to define $g(x, y)$ for $y \ne 0$ such that $g$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is $\frac{3}{4}$ of a solution:

$$
\eqalign{
g(x,y)&=g(x,0)+\alpha y\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g(x,0)}{\partial x} \cr
g(x,0)&=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix} \cr
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial g(x,0)}{\partial x}&=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-2x)+2x \\ 2b(1-2x) \end{pmatrix} \cr
\Rightarrow g(x,y)&=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix}+\alpha y\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-2x)+2x \\ 2b(1-2x) \end{pmatrix} \cr
&=\begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix}+\alpha y\begin{pmatrix}-2b(1-2x) \\ 2a(1-2x)+2x \end{pmatrix} \cr
}
$$

The scaling constant $\alpha$ can be chosen arbitrarily, EG $\alpha=\frac{1}{\left|\frac{\partial g(x,0)}{\partial x}\right|}$ to preserve certain distances, or $\alpha=1$ for simplicity. This function takes an $x$ coordinate, transforms it as if $y=0$, and then adds a vector which is perpendicular to the curve at $g(x,0)$, and is proportional to $y$.

Taking the example stated at the end of the question above with $a=b=1$, this function is $\frac{3}{4}$ of a solution in the sense that $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is surjective, and the map of the upper half of the plane $g:(-\infty,\infty)\times[0, \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is injective, but the map $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is not injective, see below for a visual demonstration:

With $\alpha=\frac{1}{\left|\frac{\partial g(x,0)}{\partial x}\right|}$:

[image]

With $\alpha=1$:

[image]

Here is the code for plotting the above graphics (change the default argument `normalise` to the function `g` from `True` to `False` to alternate between the cases above):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import shutil
import PIL

def g(x, y, a=1, b=1, alpha=1, normalise=True):
    g11 = 2*a*(1-x)*x + x*x
    g21 = 2*b*(1-x)*x
    g12 = -2*b*(1-2*x)
    g22 = (2*a*(1-2*x) + 2*x)
    if normalise:
        scale = 1 / np.sqrt(g12*g12 + g22*g22)
    else:
        scale = 1
    g1 = g11 + alpha*y*scale*g12
    g2 = g21 + alpha*y*scale*g22
    return g1, g2

def plot_g(a, b, filename, x_min=-5, x_max=7, y_min=-6, y_max=5, step=0.2):
    plt.figure(figsize=[8, 6])
    x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 500)
    plt.plot(*g(x, 0, a, b), "r", lw=2, zorder=10)
    for y in np.arange(y_min, y_max + step/2, step):
        plt.plot(*g(x, y, a, b), "k", alpha=0.2)
    y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 500)
    for x in np.arange(x_min, x_max + step/2, step):
        plt.plot(*g(x, y, a, b), "k", alpha=0.2)
    plt.xlim(-3, 3)
    plt.ylim(-3, 3)
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi=50)
    plt.close()

def make_gif(output_filename, input_filename_list):
    first_frame = PIL.Image.open(input_filename_list[0])
    first_frame.save(
        output_filename,
        format="gif",
        save_all=True,
        append_images=[PIL.Image.open(f) for f in input_filename_list[1:]],
        duration=100,
        optimise=True,
        loop=0,
    )

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
alpha_list = 0.5 * (1 - np.cos(t))
filename_list = []
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
output_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "temp_dir")
if os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(output_dir)
os.makedirs(output_dir)
for i, alpha in enumerate(alpha_list):
    a = 0.5 + alpha*1
    b = 0   + alpha*1
    filename = os.path.join(output_dir, "frame %i.png" % i)
    plot_g(a, b, filename)
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    filename_list.append(filename)

output_filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Bezier transformation.gif")
make_gif(output_filename, filename_list)
```

Here is another cool looking graphic with `a` fixed at 0.5 (and not varying between frames):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to seek a function $g(x, y)$ which locally preserves structure. Consider the identity function, which satisfies the following properties:

$$
\begin{align}
I(x, y) &= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial I}{\partial y} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}^T \frac{\partial I}{\partial y} &= 0 \\
\left\vert\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}\right\vert &= \left\vert\frac{\partial I}{\partial y}\right\vert
\end{align}
$$

It is also possible to consider a function $g(x, y)$ which satisfies similar properties in addition to the requirement in the question:

$$
\begin{align}
g(x,0) &= \begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 \\ 2b(1-x)x \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}^T \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= 0 \\
\left\vert\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right\vert &= \left\vert\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right\vert
\end{align}
$$

Firstly, in general, consider vectors $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \end{pmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{pmatrix} C & D \end{pmatrix}^T$. If these two vectors are orthogonal and of equal magnitude, then it is straightforward to derive $C$ and $D$ in terms of $A$ and $B$:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} C \\ D \end{pmatrix} &= 0 \\
\left\vert\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix}\right\vert &= \left\vert\begin{pmatrix} C \\ D \end{pmatrix}\right\vert \\
\Rightarrow \quad AC + BD &= 0 \\
A^2 + B^2 &= C^2 + D^2 \\
C &= -\frac{BD}{A} \\
\Rightarrow \quad A^2 + B^2 &= \frac{B^2 D^2}{A^2} + D^2 \\
A^2 (A^2 + B^2) &= D^2 (A^2 + B^2) \\
\Rightarrow \quad D &= \pm A \\
C &= \mp B \\
\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} C \\ D \end{pmatrix} &= \pm \begin{pmatrix} -B \\ A \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \pm \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $\begin{pmatrix} C & D \end{pmatrix}^T$ is determined apart from its sign. Now, $g(x, y)$ can be parameterised as a quadratic function (the constant term must be equal to zero for consistency with $g(x, 0)$):

$$
\begin{align}
g(x,y) &= \begin{pmatrix}2a(1-x)x+x^2 + cy^2 + dy + mxy \\ 2b(1-x)x + ey^2 + fy + nxy \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \begin{pmatrix}2a(1-2x) + 2x + my \\ 2b(1-2x) + ny \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= \begin{pmatrix}2cy + d + mx \\ 2ey + f + nx \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

An additional requirement on the sign of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ can be used to solve for the unknown coefficients:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \Rightarrow \quad\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = +\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\
\Rightarrow \quad \begin{pmatrix}2cy + d + mx \\ 2ey + f + nx \end{pmatrix} &= + \begin{pmatrix} -(2b(1-2x) + ny) \\ 2a(1-2x) + 2x + my \end{pmatrix} \\
\Rightarrow \quad &\left. \begin{matrix} 2c &=& -n \\ d &=& -2b \\ m &=& 4b \\ 2e &=& m \\ f &=& 2a \\ n &=& -4a + 2 \end{matrix} \right\} \\
\Rightarrow \quad c &= 2a - 1 \\
e &= 2b \\
\Rightarrow \quad g(x,y) &= \begin{pmatrix} 2ax + (1-2a)(x^2 - y^2) - 2by + 4bxy \\ 2bx - 2bx^2 + 2by^2 + 2ay + (2 - 4a)xy \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}
$$

Some animations of this transformation for varying $a$ and $b$ are shown below (code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jakelevi1996/aea86b76acd8e8722bbacc97044d1318#file-make_bezier_gif-py)):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]